# Is it safe to force push personal branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

Suppose I work on a personal branch called `feature`.

1. I make 5 commits.
2. I rebase on top of master.
3. I push my branch to a remote.
4. I `git reset --hard` back to commit 3.
5. I merge from master.
6. I push to the remote (I have to use `-f`).

Is that safe to do or that will cause any issues with master? I will need to merge `feature` into `master` eventually.

Comment: As long as you don't touch `master`, you're safe. Sorry, somehow thought you've rewrote master branch.

Comment: @raina77ow but when i merge master with my branch (after force push), will  that affect something as i forced push my branch previously

Comment: Merging with a branch does not rewrite its history. BTW, didn't merge with master went through fast-forward?

Comment: @raina77ow yes it was ff , but i was not sure. Sometimes after merging my branch with master , then i squash commits , and then i merge with master. i was confused if that can rewrite master

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're safe enough, as long as it really is private, and you only push to the private branch; here's why.

A branch is a specific kind of "reference", giving the ID of a commit.

When you're pushing or fetching, you are asking your git to use your repo to talk with another git and another repo.  With a `fetch` you ask your git to ask their git to give your git things you don't have yet, and then your git sets up "remote branches" for your repo, identifying new stuff brought over.  With a `push` you ask your git to send over some commits, then ask their git to make their reference(s) point to (some of) those commit(s).

When you "force push" you're making your git tell their git to set those references, *even if that might "lose" commits* (a la `git reset`).

Remember, [*references make commits reachable*](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/experimenting-with-git/references-make-commits-reachable.html).  In git, commits form a graph (a "directed acyclic" graph or DAG):

```
A <- B <- C
```

Here each single uppercase letter refers to a commit.  Each commit has a different "true name" SHA-1 (40 character apparent-nonsense like `1fc3e7aa...`).  Given one of these big long ugly SHA-1 names, like the true name for commit `C`, you (or git) read the commit and find the "parent" commit, in this case a different big ugly SHA-1 for commit `B`.  You then read that commit and find the big ugly SHA-1 for commit `A`.

But where do you get the big ugly SHA-1 for commit `C`?  You could try to memorize it, but that seems like a bad plan.  Instead, why not create a little file, like `.git/refs/heads/feature`, and write the big ugly SHA-1 into that file?  Even better, how about having *git* do that?

That's what a reference is—in this case, a branch name: a name under the `refs/heads/` category.

Now all you have to do is remember the name `feature`.  Moreover, git can look in the `refs/` directory and find *all* your references: branches (in `refs/heads/`), tags (in `refs/tags/`), notes (in `refs/notes/`), and so on.

Any commit that has a name pointing to it is, obviously, "reachable": you (or git) open the name, read the SHA-1, and go get the commit.  But any commit that is *indirectly* find-able this way is also reachable: that is, as long as we can find `C` directly, we can use it to find `B`, and then use that to find `A`.

When you do a `git reset`, you are telling your git to move a reference.  Let's extend that sequence a bit to add a new commit `D`, and make `feature` point to `D`:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- feature
```

Now let's `git reset --hard` to commit `C`.  I can't really grey-out anything in plain text but I'll shove `D` up out of the way:

```
              D
            /
A <- B <- C   <-- feature
```

We've told git to move `feature` to point to `C`.  What points to `D`?  Nothing—well, "almost nothing": git has "reflogs" and there are reflog entries keeping `D` alive for another 30 days (by default anyway).  But for normal purposes, commit `D` is gone.  It's no longer *easily* reachable, at least, and `git log` won't show it by default.  Once it's truly unreachable (no more reflog entries), git will eventually "garbage collect" it and delete it from the repository.

If you now ask `git push` to tell some *other* git to set some *other* repository's `feature` to point to commit `C`, that will lose commit `D` from there too (assuming, of course, that they had `D` in the first place).

Where things go particularly bad here is when someone else, someone using this same "other" (shared) git repo, is using—and depending-on—commit `D`.  At some point, he'll call up this shared repo and ask what's in `feature` and get back a reply saying "branch `feature` points to commit `C`" and he'll then have to figure out how to do without commit `D`, or re-provide commit `D`, or whatever.

You said no one else is using this branch (it's private), so no one else is depending on commit `D`.

One other thing to know is that while *your* reflogs will let you revive commit `D` for 30 more days, a repository that you can push-to often has reflogs disabled.  This means that as soon as you make commit `D` unreachable on the server, it's likely to get garbage-collected.

Last, if you start getting into a habit of force-pushing, be *very* careful what you force-push, lest you accidentally force-push-delete commits that other people are using/depending-on.

Comment: Truly excellent answer. Thanks for the detailed walkthrough. +1